# Error when setting up a mock config reader

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, moq

I'm trying to learn Moq by writing some simple unit tests.  Some of them have to do with a class called AppSettingsReader:

```
public class BackgroundCheckServiceAppSettingsReader : IBackgroundCheckServiceAppSettingsReader
{
    private string _someAppSetting;

    public BackgroundCheckServiceAppSettingsReader(IWorkHandlerConfigReader configReader) 
    {
        if (configReader.AppSettingsSection.Settings["SomeAppSetting"] != null)
            this._someAppSetting = configReader.AppSettingsSection.Settings["SomeAppSetting"].Value;
    }        

    public string SomeAppSetting
    {
        get { return _someAppSetting; }
    }
}
```

The interface for the class is defined like this:

```
public interface IBackgroundCheckServiceAppSettingsReader
{
    string SomeAppSetting { get; }
}
```

And the `IWorkHandlerConfigReader` (which I do not have permission to modify) is defined like so:

```
public interface IWorkHandlerConfigReader
{
    AppSettingsSection AppSettingsSection { get; }
    ConnectionStringsSection ConnectionStringsSection { get; }
    ConfigurationSectionCollection Sections { get; }

    ConfigurationSection GetSection(string sectionName);
}
```

When I write the unit test, I create a `Mock` of the `IWorkHandlerConfigReader` and try to set up the expected behavior:

```
//Arrange
string expectedReturnValue = "This_is_from_the_app_settings";
var configReaderMock = new Mock<IWorkHandlerConfigReader>();

configReaderMock.Setup(cr => cr.AppSettingsSection.Settings["SomeAppSetting"].Value).Returns(expectedReturnValue);

//Act
var reader = new BackgroundCheckServiceAppSettingsReader(configReaderMock.Object);
var result = reader.SomeAppSetting;

//Assert
Assert.Equal(expectedReturnValue, result);
```

This compiles, but when I run the test, I see the following error: `System.NotSupportedException : Invalid setup on a non-virtual (overridable in VB) member: cr => cr.AppSettingsSection.Settings["SomeAppSetting"].Value`

Is there another way to approach this other than a Mock object?  Am I misunderstanding how it should be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are actually asking dependency for `AppSettingsSection` instance. So, you should setup this property getter to return some section instance with data you need:

```
// Arrange
string expectedReturnValue = "This_is_from_the_app_settings";
var appSettings = new AppSettingsSection(); 
appSettings.Settings.Add("SomeAppSetting", expectedReturnValue);

var configReaderMock = new Mock<IWorkHandlerConfigReader>();
configReaderMock.Setup(cr => cr.AppSettingsSection).Returns(appSettings);
var reader = new BackgroundCheckServiceAppSettingsReader(configReaderMock.Object);

// Act
var result = reader.SomeAppSetting;

// Assert
Assert.Equal(expectedReturnValue, result);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!  Still getting the same error though.

Comment: @Zach looks like you are trying to create mock of `AppSettingsSection`  instead of creating its instance

Comment: AppSettingsSection fakeSettingsSection = new AppSettingsSection();  //Will this not create a new instance?

Comment: @Zach I updated answer with example of `AppSettingsSection` creation and adding some setting to it

Comment: Ok, so the second call to Setup() isn't even needed?  Once I removed that, it ran successfully.

Comment: @Zach of course - you should setup only members of mocked dependency. It has property `AppSettingsSection` so you should setup only this property getter/setter. Usually if you need to write setups on object returned by dependency, then you are definitely violating [Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) principle, which makes me stop and re-think design (if its possible)

Comment: Makes sense.  I assumed (incorrectly) that I need to define every interaction that I needed the mock to support.